# Swiper initialization not working (Cannot read property 'push' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

What I'm trying to do is really simple, or so I thought.
The Swiper.js API documents a boolean parameter which is called `init` that allows disabling the automatic initialization of the swiper.

What I would like to do is define the swiper globally like so:

```
const carousel = new Swiper(".swiper-container" , {
    freeMode: true,
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    init: false,
});
```

And initialize it when a card is clicked, like so:

```
$(".card").click(function(){
    carousel.init();
});
```

The problem with this is that the browser throws an error and the script doesn't work. Here's the error:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I don't know what the problem is because the Swiper API clearly states that after setting the `init` parameter to false, you can manually initialize it by calling `carousel.init()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem that I might have solved this problem. It seems that even if you declare the swiper globally, the swiper.js can't access it for some strange reason, so I found a workaround. Maybe this is the way the designed it, but for me, at the least, it make very little sense.

First, you need to declare your swiper inside a function, like so:

```
function carouselProperties() {
    return new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
        init: false,
        freeMode: true,
        slidesPerView: "auto",
    });
}
```

After that we go inside of the function in which the swiper should be called, in this case a click event listener.

```
$(".card").click(function(){
    // Here we define a variable that returns the swiper
    const carousel = carouselProperties()
    // Afte we define this variable we can finally call the init function
    carousel.init();
});
```

To recap:

1. You define a function which returns the swiper and its properties.
2. You call that function inside all your other functions that needs to retrieve the swiper information.

I hope this helped anyone with the same problem as I.